# Comparar subcadenas dentro de un arraylist en java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

Mi pregunta es **como puedo buscar una cadena que este repetida dentro de un arralist?** Estoy haciendo un sistema que sea capas de buscar **cualquier** nombre de archivo repetido dentro de una ruta especificada, para ello levanto todo lo que hay en la ruta y lo cargo en un `ArrayList<String>` con el siguiente metodo.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivos = new ArrayList<>();

public void buscarArchivo(File ruta) {
    //        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
            File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
    //        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
            if (archivo != null) {
                arrayArchivos.clear();
    //            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
    //                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                    if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
    //                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                        buscarArchivo(archivo[i]);
                    } else {
                        arrayArchivos.add(archivo[i].getName());
                    }
                }
                evaluarNombre();
            }
        }
```

En el metodo **evaluarNombre()**

```
public void evaluarNombre2() {
//        Evaluo si el array esta vacio.
        if (arrayArchivos != null) {
//            Recorremos el array
            for (String arrayArchivo : arrayArchivos) {
//                Mostramos solo letras y espacios ya que las cadenas a buscar pueden contener
//                num y caracteres especiales.
                String a = arrayArchivo.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").trim();
//                Partimos la cadena donde encuentre un espacio.
                String[] arraStrings = a.split(" ");
//                Llamamos al metodo contar() pasandole por parametro un arreglo.
                contar(arraStrings);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se encontro ningun archivo.");
        }
    }
```

Método **contar()**

```
private void contar(String[] arraStrings) {
//        Declaramos un contador.
        int c = 0;
//        Nos posicionamos en un elemento y recorremos el resto comparando.
        for (int i = 0; i < arraStrings.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arraStrings.length; j++) {
//                Si los nombres de las cadenas son iguales, el contador se ingrementa.
                if (arraStrings[i].substring(0, arraStrings[i].lastIndexOf("")).equals(arraStrings[j].substring(0, arraStrings[j].lastIndexOf("")))) {
                    c++;
                }
            }
//            Evaluo que el contador sea mayor a 1.
            if (c > 1) {
                System.out.println("El archivo '" + arraStrings[i] + "' Se repite " + c);
            }
        }
    }
```

Los archivos que cargo en el arraylist son estos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso son solo nombres de archivos **mp3** pero es aplicable a **cualquier** tipo de archivo se entiende? 
La salida que obtengo es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como se aprecia en la primer imagen solo el archivo

**02. - Maluma - Corazon - Dexter Remix (Global Music11) - copia**

Es el que esta repetido, que estoy haciendo mal? Agradecería mucho su ayuda en verdad, desde ya gracias.

Comment: El algoritmo no funciona por culpa de Maluma :P Ya en serio, creo que tu problema está en el replaceAll que haces con la expresión regular. ¿Estás seguro que identifica lo que buscas? Y lo otro, a tu definición le falta especificar bien qué sería considerado un duplicado (pensando en que aplica para cualquier tipo de archivo).

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea buena idea separar por palabras, porque estás buscando justo esa palabra repetida en cada línea, y tomaría por palabras (como remix) que están en otras filas.
Según tu ejemplo, solo debería mostrar los que tienen parte del nombre:

`02. - Maluma - Corazon - Dexter Remix (Global Music11) - copia.mp3
02. - Maluma - Corazon - Dexter Remix (Global Music11).mp3`

... los quieres considerar  como *repetido*.

En tal caso, ignora la extensión:

```
//...
   String fileName=archivo[i].getName();
   arrayArchivos.add(fileName.substring(0,fileName.length()-4)); //extension + punto
//...
```

Y luego, en tu `evaluarNombre()`

```
//...
 for (String arrayArchivo : arrayArchivos) {
    int cuenta=0;
    for(String n:arrayArchivos){
      if (arrayArchivo.indexOf(n)>=0) cuenta++;
    }
     System.out.println("El archivo '" + arrayArchivo  + "' Se repite " + cuenta);
 }
//...
```